# any way to call mlcp from java apps

Tags: maven, marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp

I'm new to Marklogic and mlcp. I'm working on marklogin 9.0-8. I wnat to use mlcp to load content, but since some parameters may need to be dynamically built based on content, does anyone know if it is possible to call mlcp from java application?

Thanks a lot,
Helen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic provides two Java-based ways to load content: MLCP and DMSDK. MLCP is intended to be used as a command-line tool (and I believe that's the only supported use).

The Data Movement SDK, on the other hand, is specifically intended to offer very similar functionality in the form of a JAR, making it easy to access from a Java application. I encourage you to look into using that instead.

- [tutorial](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-movement-sdk)
- [JavaDoc](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/datamovement/package-summary.html)
- [Asynchronous Multi-Document Operations](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement#chapter)
- [12-minute video intro to DMSDK](https://mlu.marklogic.com/ondemand/44eb2418)
- [common tasks made easier through ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/DMSDK-Tasks)

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried to build application with DMSDK, but I got error. I'll update my original question. Can you help me?

Comment: @Helen Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of updating your question with a new question, please accept the most correct/helpful answer and create a separate new question. SO is intended to be helpful not only for the person asking a question, but for other people with the same question in the future. By "moving the goalposts" of your question, you make the post confusing, and it wastes the time of the person answering because you have not given them credit for their initially correct answer.

Comment: Sorry for that. I will create a new question and remove my updates from this one.